# Convert from ITRS to ICRS using astropy

Tags: astronomy, astropy

Say pleases is it possible using AstroPy to transform ITRS(International Terrestrial Reference System) to ICRS(International Celestial Reference System)?  I have read the documentation and understand how to do ICRS to ITRS conversions, but not sure how to go the other way.

Comment: Likely, did you read the docs?

Comment: Yes, from ICRS to ITRS i can do transformation but vice versa i have no idea

Comment: If the transformation is a matrix, simply invert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the transformations implemented in Astropy are bi-directional (see, e.g., [the transform graph](http://docs.astropy.org/en/latest/coordinates/index.html#module-astropy.coordinates) that visualizes the possible transformations). So, yes, it is possible to transform from the ITRS to the ICRS frame. You have to create an instance of the `ITRS` class by specifying the Cartesian coordinates of the point of interest. For example:

```
import astropy.coordinates as coord
import astropy.units as u
itrs = coord.ITRS(x=150*u.km, y=300*u.km, z=-210*u.km)
```

Then you can transform to the ICRS frame with:

```
icrs = itrs.transform_to(coord.ICRS)
```